# Python запись ошибок в .txt файл

Tags: python

Есть ли возможность записывать ошибки в текстовый документ не используя блоки try except в Python? Т.К. логи этих ошибок мне записывать не нужно, а вот, не очевидные ошибки которые будут получаться в ходе эксплуатации скрипта, хотелось бы сохранять без действий пользователя, для дальнейшего исправления, спасибо.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1956228/7485582 https://stackoverflow.com/a/33500446/7485582

Comment: Чем вам try-except не угодил?

Comment: @andreymal, все известные мне ошибки я обработала через try-exept, а вот что смогут получить пользователи скрипта, я не знаю, и мне нужно видеть эти ошибки

Comment: @Kristina просто пишите `except Exception:`, оно отловит абсолютно все ошибки

Answer (score 1):

да оное возможно реализовать при помощи модуля logging

```
import logging
import logging.handlers as handlers
s = handlers.RotatingFileHandler('file/log.txt', mode='a', maxBytes=24,backupCount=2, encoding=None, delay=0) 
s = logging.StreamHandler()#FileHandler указать для работы а не демки 
f = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s %(levelno)s: %(message)s in %(pathname)s line  %(lineno)s at %(asctime)s from %(name)s data %(stack_info)s')
l = logging.Logger(name='simple_example')
s.setFormatter(f)
l.addHandler(s)
l.setLevel(22)
l.info('not display')
logging.addLevelName('Test',23)
l.log(23,'display this')
#Test 23: display this in file.py line  10 at 2020-04-17 15:35:15,397 from simple_example data None
```